# Does consuming Creatine harm the kidneys, or does it artificially elevate serum Creatinine?

Tags: proteins, kidney

How does taking the supplement Creatine affect the kidney?

I took Creatine 30 mins before a blood test.

I am curious if is it POSSIBLE that the test will be falsely elevated by measuring Creatine or its byproducts in my blood?

Or is it possible that taking Creatine harms the kidneys?

Comment: Welcome user!  There are several different issues going on here in your question.  First, we can't give medical advice, so I'm editing it. Second, your protein intake is pretty extreme, you should probably have a dietician advising you if you're going that route.  There is actual evidence for what you do and do not need for muscle building, which you might benefit from learning.

Answer (score 2):

Can it be falsely elevated?  Yes: according to [this study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17851680), creatine in the bloodstream peaks between 1 and 3 hours after consumption, depending on the form in which it is consumed.

Is it possible that taking creatine harms the kidneys?  Maybe.  There have been [reports of kidney damage as a result of taking creatine](http://www.mayoclinic.org/drugs-supplements/creatine/safety/hrb-20059125), but small-scale controlled trials of typical performance-enhancing doses ([1](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12701816), [2](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18188581)) do not show problems.

If you want to know what sort of shape your kidneys are in, don't take creatine before a blood test.  The above-mentioned pharmokinetics study says that a 28-day waiting period will return your muscle creatine levels to baseline values; 8-24 hours is sufficient for your blood creatine levels.